# How to manipulate form elements in jQuery submit handler?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to manipulate some form elements (add, remove) before they get sent to the browser.

I can capture the submit event and get a form object but I did not find a way to access the input elements from the `form` object in the `dataAndTime2dateTime` function.

```
var dataAndTime2dateTime = function(form) {
    console.log(form);
    // add element called 'dateTime'
    // remove element called 'date'
};

$( "#searchFirst" ).submit(dataAndTime2dateTime);
```

How can I get the form input elements from the `form` object and manipulate them?

**Update:**

From what I learned from the comments i updated my code to

```
var dataAndTime2dateTime = function(event) {
    console.log($(this).filter("input[name='searchDateTo']").val());
};
```

But that returns `undefined` instead of the value of the form field.

Comment: [:input Selector](http://api.jquery.com/input-selector/).

Comment: The submit handler argument is the event object and not your form DOM instance. You can refer to your form with `this` keyword within your handler

Answer (score -1):

One way to do this is by first stopping the browser from submitting. like so:

```
$('#searchFirst').submit(dataAndTime2dateTime(e));
```

The variable e 'catches' the submit event and passes it to your function. You can then block prevent the browser from doing its usual thing by using the event.preventDefault() function.

`var dataAndTime2dateTime = function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    // do stuff
    // then send manually
}`

a ready-to-go method for retreiving form elements is

`$.fn.serializeObject = function() {
    var o = {};
    var a = this.serializeArray();
    $.each(a, function() {
        if (o[this.name] !== undefined) {
            if (!o[this.name].push) {
                o[this.name] = [o[this.name]];
            }
            o[this.name].push(this.value || '');
        } else {
            o[this.name] = this.value || '';
        }
    });
    return o;
};`

You can use this function like so:

`var formSerializedObject = $('#searchFirst').serializeObject();`

Be sure that each of your form elements has a unique name.

You can then easily manipulate this string and send it to your api.

Comment: You are executing the callback function in the `submit` call, which will set the actual submit callback to undefined unless the function returns something, in that case it will set the callback to whatever is returned.

Comment: Sorry, I have no idea what your code does, nor how it could answer my question.